# How do I re-arrange the $node->taxonomy array back into a hierarchical tree?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

In a node I'm creating, there is a hierarchical select widget. The widget saves the 'deepest' term in a given taxonomy.

These terms come out in the $node->taxonomy array in tpl files.

I want to build the tree right back up to the last parent. How do I do this? What is the algorithm? I have a complete sphagetti mess that's not even worth posting here, right now. I have a feeling there's recursion involved somewhere, but I'm missing the specifics - pseudocode please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of an API function that can do this but the following code should help:

```
$tid = 4; // Your term id

// Grab all of the parents of this term (including the term itself) 
// in reverse order.
$parents = array_reverse(taxonomy_get_parents_all($tid));

$tree = array();

// Get a reference to the root of the array. This reference will be updated
// in each iteration of the loop to refer to the array of children added to
// the term.
$ref = &$tree; 
foreach ($parents as $term) {
  // Add the current term to the relevant root/children array.
  $ref[$term->tid] = $term;

  // If the current term is NOT the original child term, we add an array of
  // children to the term and update the array reference to point to it.
  if ($term->tid != $tid) {
    $term->children = array();
    $ref = &$term->children;
  }
}
```

By the time that loop has run the `$tree` variable will be a hierarchical representation of the original term's parents, with each child term in the `children` key of it's parent term object.

I've only tested this on terms that have a single parent; if you've got terms with multiple parents I think you'll struggle to get this to work.

Comment: Thank you! This worked exactly like I needed to, giving me exactly what I wanted. I just found out the childless terms and fed them to this loop, and it gave out a perfect tree I could recursively iterate through to display. You saved my life.